# Manually installed font looks bit-mappy and conflicts with microtype

Tags: fonts, pdftex, installing

Following the instructions [here](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/matching-math-fonts-to-text/) I tried to install the Vollkorn font. Now, after some fiddling (see the comments on the above linked blog post) I managed to get the font to work, but there are some problems. First, it looks kind of jagged.
[image: Vollkorn looks bitmappy]

Second, loading the `microtype` package seems to break it. I get this error:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LY1/vkn/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LY1/vkn/b/n' tried instead on input line 17.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.

                   \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
l.22 \end{document}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Also, running `pdffonts test.pdf` gets me some odd results:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       4  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       5  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no       6  0
```

Something isn't working, but I'm not quite sure what. Any pointers on how to diagnose the problem?

Minimal example (although you probably could have worked this out yourself)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{vollkorn}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Bold} \textit{Italic}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[Log with Microtype](https://gist.github.com/822174) | [Log without Microtype](https://gist.github.com/822176)

Comment: Make a small complete example (with microtype) that demonstrates the problem. Then remove microtype and compile with pdflatex. Show the complete example and the log-file of compilation without microtype.

Comment: Did you make a map-file for your vollkorn fonts? If yes: what is its content and is this content in /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map?

Comment: I think part of the problem is that the ubuntu package version of texlive does all kinds of weird stuff like have all these files be generated by a bunch of other files in a different directory, so keeping track of all this stuff is tricky... I don't the `pdftex.map` has lines for Vollkorn in it, but there is a `.map` file for Vollkorn in the `dvips` folder

Comment: @Seamus I guess you need a .map in `~/texmf/fonts/map` (and update maps then).

Comment: I copied the contents of the Vollkorn map file in the `dvips` folder to `~/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map` and ran `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=~/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map` and now it works with microtype, looks better and `pdffonts` tells me my fonts are TrueType. Fonts still seem like black magic to me.

Comment: @Seamus: If you want your problem to be solved fast you should try to be more precise. Don't write "there is a .map in the dvips folder" but "there is `ExactName.map` in `ExactPath`". Apart from this: Try on the command line `updmap-sys --enable Map=mapfile`. Check if the command updated the pdftex.map and if it now contains your font entries.

Comment: `/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map` now includes lines for Vollkorn and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Seamus: If you don't like black magic, switch to XeTeX or LuaTeX, which support OTF fonts out of the box.

Comment: @Philipp I intend to, and I intend to remove the debian texlive package and replace it with a texlive 2010 I manage myself, but those are big-ish projects, whereas this is something I can fiddle with for ten minutes when I have a little spare time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I'd got the right lines added to the `pdftex.map` file, the bitmappiness went away and `pdffonts` gave the right answers.

The "right lines" in this case were all the lines for the relevant font "Vollkorn" which I copied from the `dvips.map` file. That is, I searched the map file for lines that had "Vollkorn" in them, and copied those into the `pdftex.map` file.

[In fact, I think for this particular font, it had its own map file `/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/friedrichalthausen/friedrichalthausen.map` but in general, the procedure would be as above...]

Comment: Erm, and what are "the right lines"?

Comment: Good point. I've added some detail, but like I've said elsewhere, fonts are still a "Dark Art" to me...

Comment: You should not change pdftex.map manually. It will be overwritten if you (or the package manager when installing a font) calls updmap or updmap-sys (depending on your texsystem and the location of pdftex.map). Map files are enabled with `updmap-sys --enable Map=mapfile` or `updmap --enable Map=mapfile`

Comment: I should have answered this question at the time. I can't actually remember what I did now. I only answered it to get it off the unanswered list. Perhaps it's best if I just delete the question. (Unless someone wants to provide a _good_ answer...