# Auto expansion only with scalable fonts

Tags: fonts, pdftex

From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/pdftex-error-font-expansion-auto-expansion-is-only-possible-with-scalable) I understand that this is due to requesting microtype operations on bitmap fonts.

My problem is that the exact code I'm compiling works fine on my laptop (OS X 10.6, TexLive and packages from MacPorts), but on my new desktop at work (RHEL6) it errors out with the pdftex error in the title.

I'm writing an article for a conference, and to get the stylesheet working I had to install eco.sty to a private texmf tree, so I suspect there's something I've missed in the install procedure, but I can't see why. I've installed `eco.sty` and the fd-files to `~/texmf/tex/latex/eco` and the tfm and vf files to `~/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/eco` and `~/texmf/fonts/vf/public/eco` respectively (as the `INSTALL` file told me to). And I remembered to `texhash` afterwards.

Is there something else I need to do, like something related to `updmap`? [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10801/manually-installed-font-looks-bit-mappy-and-conflicts-with-microtype) would seem to indicate that this might be the culprit, but eco doesn't come with any map files, nor can I seem to find any fitting map files on my laptop.

Comment: Without an example it is hard to answer your question. However, just a general tip. You could consider install MacTeX 2011 on your Mac and the TeXLive 2011 on RHEL6. So you have exactly the same distributions (well, except binaries., etc.) on both platform and that will make your life much easier. I use both Mac and RHEL too, and the TeX distributed with RHEL is simply too old. MacPorts, in my opinion makes life harder rather than easier. Homebrew is a much better alternative

Comment: Yeah, I've been meaning to replace MacPorts with Homebrew, just not gotten around to it yet. Just ignoring the system TexLive on RHEL and installing my own definitely sounds like a good idea as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would very much easier to help you if you would some vital informations like a minimal example that demonstrates your error, log file and the exact wording of your error message.

As I have to guess: Install the cm-super fonts. If you have a modern texlive you should be able to do it with the texlive package manager tlmgr.

Comment: Yeah, sorry 'bout that. Could definitely been clearer. The error message was simply "Auto expansion only with scalable fonts". But installing cm-super fixed it, so you're pretty good at guessing it seems. =) Thanks!

Comment: @arnsholt, installing `cm-super` fixed an identical error for me as well.